# Passing file to data = {} not a folder path

Tags: python

Good day everyone I would like to ask if how to pass a file inside the data = {} My code below is passing a csv file but when I print the data the output is the file path of the csv not the file of sample.csv. I'm using a python. when I use the csv_content i got this error.

Exception has occurred: TypeError
Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

here's my code:

```
api_url = 'test.com/sample_api'
csv = '/home/user/Desktop/folder/folder2/csv/file.csv'
def post_request(self, api_url, csv):

        with open(csv_file_path, 'rb') as file:
            csv_content = file.read()
            # print(csv_file_path)
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }

        data = {
            "id": "1"
            "name": "test"
            "data_file":
            [
                {"filename": csv, "file": csv_content },
            ]
        }
        print(data)

        response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
        print(response.text)
```

I try the code provided i want to expect the sample.csv file will be the output not the path.

Comment: you did not use csv_content = file.read() in your program.

Comment: This code is incomplete.  The `post_request()` function is _defined_ but never _called_.  The variable `csv_file_path` is undefined.  etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import requests

api_url = 'test.com/sample_api'
csv_file_path = '/home/user/Desktop/folder/folder2/csv/file.csv'

def post_request(api_url, csv_path):
    with open(csv_path, 'rb') as file:
        csv_content = file.read()

    data = {
        "data_file": [{"filename": "sample.csv", "file": csv_content}]
    }

    response = requests.post(api_url, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}, json=data)
    print(response.text)

post_request(api_url, csv_file_path)
```

Comment: Exception has occurred: TypeError
Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Comment: You may need to encode the bytes with base64 before data. Hard to test without the files